# Who does the verb "argues" and preposition "to" refer to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At least **to argues** E.Pessen in his iconoclastic study of the very rich in the US between 1825 and 1850.

I don't quiet understand both *to* and *argues*. Does *argues* refers to *E.Pessen*?

Can anyone please turn this sentence into the normal form, such as "E.Pessen argues XXX"?

Comment: It means nothing to me, I'm afraid. There's a mistake there of some kind.

Comment: Yep. Definitely a mistake. Could you provide more context?

Comment: @warl0ck: Don't worry about it. You won't lose brownie points whether it gets closed or not. You could "flag" it for moderator attention if you don't have the rep to "vote to close" or "delete", but there's no need to force a mod to pay attention if they have better things to do. It's not "bad" that you asked, since you had no way of knowing the answer at the time. I only think it should be closed because now you've got your answer it's probably not important for future visitors.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's enough the OP selects "it doesn't belong here" from the flagging dialog, and then a reason for closing the question (e.g. "too localized"); in that way, the flag is visible also to 10k users.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: But this completely pointless question is **still here!** Never mind closing, it should have been deleted months ago! I can't imagine why seven people were minded to upvote it - a simple comment left long enough for OP to realise what was going on would be all that politeness requires. This sort of drivel just dilutes ELU to the point where it's rapidly losing credibility, IMHO.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know. If the OP would have voted to close it, it would require 2 other users to close it (OPs see the link to close their own question). Until the question is not closed, 10k users cannot vote to deleted it. 20k user can vote to delete it right from the moment it is closed, while other users must wait.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, I guess we just have to wait unless/until some others vote to close, so we can vote to delete. Is there a "site protocol" on the idea of editing the question text so it comes up on "active" items, thus drawing attention to get it closed?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The front page shows the questions basing on when they are edited, a new answer is added, or an old answer has been edited. As I edited this question, it has been jumped on the front page, and hopefully somebody will notice it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a typo. "to" should be "so". It was fixed in later editions:

See ["The Official Guide to the GRE Revised General Test", from the Educational Testing Service](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gGLgekNMQRQC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=At%20least%20to%20argues%20E.Pessen%20in%20his%20iconoclastic%20study%20of%20the%20very%20rich%20in%20the%20US%20between%201825%20and%201850#&source=bl&ots=71Jbwe7R_m&sig=aX63TUussueuFv15wr9kLT4DPMU&hl=en&ei=F6OaTtHXGsOX8QOFvpDfBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false): (second sentence on that page)

The quote should be, and is now:

> At least so argues E.Pessen in his iconoclastic study of the very rich in the US between 1825 and 1850